gdal2tiles SRS problem, works in GDAL 2 not GDAL 3

gdalsrsinfo -V 'PROJCS["Mars_2015_Ocentric_Equirectangular_clon_0",GEOGCS["GCS_Mars_2015_Ocentric",DATUM["D_Mars_2015",SPHEROID["Mars_2015",3396190,169.894447223612]],PRIMEM["Reference Meridian",0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Equirectangular"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]'

Validate Succeeds ...
However, when using this with the -s option to gdal2tiles.py, I get
RuntimeError: Cannot find coordinate operations from PROJCRS["Mars_2015_Ocentric_Equirectangular_clon_0",BASEGEOGCRS["GCS_Mars_2015_Ocentric",DATUM["Mars (2015)",ELLIPSOID["Mars_2015",3396190,169.894447223612,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],ID["IAU",49901]],PRIMEM["Reference Meridian",0,ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],CONVERSION["unnamed",METHOD["Equidistant Cylindrical",ID["EPSG",1028]],PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",0,ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8823]],PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],ID["EPSG",8802]],PARAMETER["False easting",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8806]],PARAMETER["False northing",0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],ID["EPSG",8807]]],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS["easting",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]],AXIS["northing",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]]]' to EPSG:3857'
This worked previously in GDAL 2.x, but I'd like to be using some of the new options in GDAL 3.

I suggest editing the title to mention that the source SRS is from Mars.

Projinfo from source to target:
projinfo -s @mars.prj -t EPSG:3857
createOperations() failed with: Source and target ellipsoid do not belong to the same celestial body (Earth vs Mars). You may override this check by setting the PROJ_IGNORE_CELESTIAL_BODY environment variable to YES.

A new trial by applying the hint:
set PROJ_IGNORE_CELESTIAL_BODY=YES

projinfo -s @mars.prj -t EPSG:3857
Candidate operations found: 1
-------------------------------------
Operation No. 1:

unknown id, Inverse of unnamed + Ballpark geographic offset from GCS_Mars_2015_Ocentric to WGS 84 + Popular Visualisation Pseudo-Mercator, unknown accuracy, World, has ballpark transformation

PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline
...

Set the environment variable PROJ_IGNORE_CELESTIAL_BODY for your system and make a new trial.
